# Check if a file name exists more than once in a FileInfo array

Tags: c#

```
FileInfo[] folderFiles = folder.GetFiles();

foreach (FileInfo file in folderFiles)
{

    int fileCount = 0;

    StreamWriter sw = null;

    string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.Name);

    string[] brkedfilename = fileName.Split('_');

    string stringToCheck = brkedfilename[3];

    for (int i = 0; i <= folderFiles.Count() - 1; i++)
    {
        string fileName2 = folderFiles[i].Name;

        string[] brkedfilename2 = fileName2.Split('_');

        if (brkedfilename2[3] == stringToCheck)
        {
            fileCount = ++fileCount;

            if (fileCount == 2)
           {
                sw = new StreamWriter(folderPath + "/" + newFileName, true);
                sw.WriteLine(stringToCheck + "  " + "--" + "  " + "Repeated in folder " + " " + folder.Name);
                sw.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

By doing this way, if a file name is existing 2 times , it is writing that file name 2 times. But I want it to write only once.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: How do you distinguish which file you want to write to *without* the extension? Is there any criteria?

Comment: if the condition only is to check if the filename exists 2 time, then you can return from you function or break the for loop after sw.Close();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use LINQ to find files with same brkedNames:

```
var repeatedFiles = from f in folderFiles
                    let brkedName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f.Name).Split('_')[3]
                    group f by brkedName into g
                    where g.Count() > 1
                    select new
                    {
                        BrkedName = g.Key,
                        Count = g.Count(),
                        Files = g
                    };
```

This query groups all files by 4th part of splitted names (note: as in your original code I don't check if there is at least 4 parts) and then select groups with more than one file. It also provides some stats - brked name, count of files with same name and files collection.

```
foreach(var group in repeatedFiles)
   sw.WriteLine($"{group.BrkedName} -- repeated {group.Count} times in {folder.Name}");
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir...I tried the above code and it worked...So happyyy.. :)

Answer (score 1):

I propose use a hashset. Hashset cannot contain duplicate elements. When You add duplicate element do hashset method `Add` return `false` and program go on witout error but hashset will not take duplicate element

```
var duplicate = new HashSet<string>();

    foreach (FileInfo file in folderFiles)
    {
        int fileCount = 0;

        StreamWriter sw = null;

        string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.Name);

        string[] brkedfilename = fileName.Split('_');

        string stringToCheck = brkedfilename[3];

         if (!duplicate.Add(stringToCheck))
            {
                sw = new StreamWriter(folderPath + "/" + newFileName, true);
                sw.WriteLine(stringToCheck + "  " + "--" + "  " + "Repeated in folder " + " " + folder.Name);
                sw.Close();
            }
    }
```

Program adds each element do `Hashset` duplicate when element is in `Hashset` already `Add` metod return `false` when I know the element is in the `Hashset` and I save in the file as You want

Comment: Here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

You can use Dictionary  ( filename, repeat time) to list all filename exist. And after that you can loop the dictionary to write to console.